# ionic run android -l (with livereload) no longer working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

After this weekend I have been trying the command to livereload on android (`ionic run android -l -c`) which makes workflow faster but it's no longer working, no error messages.

I tried:

reinstalling npm (removed npm_modules) and once again `npm install`
uninstall and reinstalling cordova and ionic
updating ionic cli
no errors in css/scss file
restarting PC many times after doing all these.

**Any of you had the same problem, any workarounds?**

---

I checked my index.html and config.xml and both seem fine. As I know sometimes errors in this files might bother the livereload, so I'm posting them both here maybe someone else sees something I'm missing:

This is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="az-app" id="index" ng-controller="IndexController">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <!-- compiled css output -->
  <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- angular filters -->
  <script src="lib/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js"></script>

  <!-- iOS9 Window location bug patch -->
  <script src="js/ios9-angular.patch.js"></script>

  <!-- Controllers -->
  <script src="js/controllers/IndexController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/walkthrough/PolicyController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/walkthrough/WalkthroughController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/DoctorsDirController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/meds-refund/MedsRefundWalkController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/meds-refund/MedsRefundController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/meds-refund/MedsCamScannerController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/consult-refund/ConsultRefundWalkController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/consult-refund/ConsultRefundController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/consult-refund/SelectsController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/consult-refund/ConsultCamController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/med-authorization/MedAuthorizationWalkController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/med-authorization/MedAuthorizationController.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/med-authorization/MedAuthCamController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/what-to-do/WhatToDoController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/controllers/benefits/LifeBenefitsController.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Directives -->
  <script src="js/directives/moreInfo.js"></script>

  <!-- Models  -->
  <script src="js/services/Config.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/CameraScannerFactory.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/StorageFactory.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services/WebServiceFactory.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<ion-nav-bar class="nav-bar">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"  side="primary">
    <i class="nav-bar-back-arrow ion-android-arrow-back"></i>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-buttons class="button-clear" side="secondary">
    <button class="nav-bar-btn" ng-click="goToDashboard()">
      <img class="bdoard-btn" src="img/icons/ic_dboard_btn.png"/>
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


</body>
</html>
```

my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.azseguros.anglogold" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>AZ Seguros - Anglo Gold</name>
  <description>
    </description>
  <author email="alaorden@banshai.com" href="http://banshai.com.com/">El equipo Banshai</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="git add*"/>
  <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*"/>
  <access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="14+"/>
  <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect"/>
  <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57"/>
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114"/>
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40"/>
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80"/>
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50"/>
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100"/>
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60"/>
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180"/>
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72"/>
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144"/>
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76"/>
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152"/>
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29"/>
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58"/>
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87"/>
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750"/>
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242"/>
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208"/>
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048"/>
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024"/>
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536"/>
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768"/>
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="NSAppTransportSecurity" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
      <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
    </config-file>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check your firewall setting, add "node.exe" to excluded program.
Press Win+R, run "WF.msc", add "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" to exclude program on both incoming and outgoing role.

I just solve many livereload problems with this trick, including blank screen, unsuccessful livereload etc.
Note that ionic will open two port for "ionic cordova run android -l", one for html page(:8100) and one for websocket(as mean as livereload).